# Cassandra with Hadoop

Tags: cassandra, hadoop

Cassandra uses Cassandra File System (CFS) and Hadoop uses Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)

I'm already using Pig over HDFS and i would like to install Cassandra.

Having additional servers for Cassandra is might inefficient to the fact that i already have Hadoop setup.

**Can Cassandra use HDFS instead of CFS?**

Answer (score 1):

The [Hadoop Support section of the Cassandra Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport) says:

> Cassandra's Hadoop support implements the same interface as HDFS to
>   achieve input data locality (see cluster configuration for details on
>   data locality and how to split your analytic and realtime read loads).

So the answer appears to be, "yes".